# How to install or run Ubuntu on Windows 8 using WUBI?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, windows-8

Okay, so I have a Windows 8.1 PC, an ASUS X202E-DB21T. It has 500 GB of HDD. I want to use Ubuntu so that I can build a Firefox OS build, but Windows is not supported. I don't want to install Ubuntu directly. Wubi might help but it says Win 8 is not compatible.

How can I do this? Also, if I do install it, can I use my tablet as a USB stick? I don't want to buy a USB Stick. I could erase all of the SDCard data and put the .iso file there and boot from there.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is no longer supported. I would very much recomend that you not try that. 
A much better way is to install Virtual box (virtual machine software from Oracle which is free). That works really well in Windows. Then you can install Ubuntu on that.

That will give you the added benefit of making snapshots of your Ubuntu environment and roll back to those if you messed things up

Hope that helps